# Como criar um alias no PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Trabalho com projetos que utilizam versões diferentes do node e quero criar um alias para versões no PowerShell.

Ex:

```
nvm-version-default nvm use 14.17.3
nvm-version-oldProject nvm use 12.20.0
```

Comment: Acredito que este link possa te ajudar bastante [Set-Alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.1#:~:text=The%20Set%2DAlias%20cmdlet%20creates%20an%20alias%20to%20the%20function,on%20the%20PowerShell%20command%20line.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo:

```
function Get-SystemBootTime{
      systeminfo | find "System Boot Time"
}

Set-Alias -Name bt -Value Get-SystemBootTime
```

Executando o alias:

```
PS > bt
System Boot Time:          7/20/2021, 8:49:23 AM
```

Comment: Interessante, mas quando fecho o terminal o Alias não fica salvo.  
`function useNodeDefault{
    nvm use 14.17.3
}

Set-Alias -Name nvm-use-default -Value useNodeDefault -Scope Global`

Comment: Nesse caso você precisa criar um profile e adicionar o alias nele. [PowerShell Profile](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1)